# I use CRegKey to open some, but this m_hKey != 0

Tags: c++, mfc, registry

I want to get JDk path by the Registry, this path is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Development Kit\\1.8
```

when I use:

```
CRegKey.open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Development Kit\\1.8")
```

it throws expression m_hKey != 0. so what's happening ? How to fix this bug?

Here is my code：

```
// Get Java environment variable install path
CRegKey key;
wchar_t JavaHome[40];
ULONG szJavaHome = 40;
bool rest = key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Development Kit\\1.8");
if (key.m_hKey == 0)
    MessageBox(L"11");
rest = key.QueryStringValue(L"JavaHome", JavaHome, &szJavaHome);
```

Comment: if (::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"\\SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Development Kit\\1.8", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey))            When i use the Win Api ,the hKey value is 0 too--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply use the [`CRegKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xka57xy4.aspx) variable `key` after trying to [`Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkaby1xz.aspx) it, without checking the return value of it.

```
auto retOpenKey = key.Open(...); //LONG not bool
if (ERROR_SUCCESS == retOpenKey)
{
    //Ok do stuff with key
}
else
    auto err = GetLastError();
```

[System error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and / or [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can also look in the implementation of the function, and debug in there, as it is inline in the header:

```
inline LONG CRegKey::Open(
    _In_ HKEY hKeyParent,
    _In_opt_z_ LPCTSTR lpszKeyName,
    _In_ REGSAM samDesired) throw()
{
    ATLASSUME(hKeyParent != NULL);
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LONG lRes = m_pTM != NULL ?
        m_pTM->RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyParent, lpszKeyName, 0, samDesired, &hKey) :
        RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyParent, lpszKeyName, 0, samDesired, &hKey);
    if (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        lRes = Close();
        ATLASSERT(lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        m_hKey = hKey;
#if WINVER >= 0x0501
        m_samWOW64 = samDesired & (KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
#endif
    }
    return lRes;
}
```

Comment: When i use GetLastError(), it return 0-- what happend?

Comment: but thanks for you , i use Win API to do this .but it happend some error again 2333. so -- maybe my path is bad?

Comment: Thanks ,Finally i use FormatMessage to get some info , this tip me files not found -- so  maybe my write registry path is bad --